# How to make an iterator point to the same element as another one in a C++ set?

Tags: c++, iterator, set

There are 2 iterators to the sets of the same type:

```
    typename TFunction <T>::Type ::const_iterator i1 = f1.begin();
    typename TFunction <T>::Type ::const_iterator i2 = f2.begin();
```

After several steps i1 points to some element of f1 having index = index1 (it may not be known). I need to set the second iterator i2 to the element of f2 having the equal index as index1...

Can this be done without a conversion of i1 to the index?

Comment: The spaces you have in between the type are a little bit confusing to me

Comment: Find index: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796503/index-or-position-in-stdset , get index: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907435/get-element-from-arbitrary-index-in-set

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `std::advance` as:

```
std::advance(it2, index1); //increments it2 index1 times!
```

Done!

If you dont know the value of `index1`, then you can always compute it using the *current* `it1` as:

```
auto index1 = std::distance(f1.begin(), it1);
```

:-)

---

Note that `std::advance` returns `void` so you cannot write this:

```
fun(f2.begin(), std::advance(it2, index1)); //error
```

Instead if you have to write this:

```
std::advance(it2, index1); //first advance
fun(f2.begin(), it2);        //then use it
```

So to ease such usages, `std::next` is added in C++11:

```
fun(f2.begin(), std::next(f2.begin(), index1)); //ok, don't even need it2!
```

---

BTW, in C++11, you could use `auto` instead of typename thingy:

```
auto it1 = f1.cbegin(); //cbegin() returns const_iterator
auto it2 = f2.cbegin(); //cbegin() returns const_iterator
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Suppose index1 to be unknown; we do not want to use std::distance do compute it. Is there any way in C++ 03, without the conversion i1 to the index1, to do it?

Comment: You can also compute `index1` as `auto index1=std::distance(f1.begin(), i1);`. Edited the answer also.

Comment: Oh I realized I wrote `it1` and `it2` instead of `i1` and `i2`. Iterators variables are customarily written as `it` in C++.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear what your index is, but if you have moved `i1` you can use `std::distance` to see how much by and then use `std::advance`

```
std::advance(i2, std::distance(f1.begin(), i1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::advance(i2,index1)` to advance `i2`.

Comment: Given the specifics of the question, consider providing a little more context here