# Direct access to element of STL "set"

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, set

How can I directly access a element of a **STL** **set** by index??

I got errors **no match for 'operator+'**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
..
set < long  long > s;
set <long long > :: iterator it;
it = s.begin() + k;
       cout << (*it);
```

here k is the index of require element.

fore more specifically i want to solve a problem using set.

here is the problem link:
[k-th divisor](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/762/A)

and this is my error code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    set<long long> s;
    set<long long >:: iterator it;
    long long i,n,k, ln;
    cin >> n>> k;
        ln = sqrt(n);
        for(i = 1; i <= ln; i++)
        {
            if(n%i == 0)
            {
                s.insert(i);
                s.insert(n/i);
            }
        }
        if(s.size() < k)
            printf("-1\n");
        else
        {
            it = s.begin() + k;
            cout << (*it);
        }

        s.clear();
    return 0;
}
```

help me out

Comment: The elements of a set aren't indexed. They're found by key.

Comment: Looks like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Don't include<bits/stdc++.h>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [index or position in std::set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796503/index-or-position-in-stdset)

Comment: why ?? @manni66

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this expression to work:

```
s.begin() + k;
```

Iterator must satisfy the [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) concept. As stated in the [`std::set` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) its iterator is [BidirectionalIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator), so you cannot add an offset to it. What you can use is [`std::next()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next):

```
it = std::next( s.begin(), k );
```

but you need to be aware this will increase the iterator k times. Or you can change your container to one which provides a random access iterator (for example `std::vector`).

Comment: it's not working.i got **it's a not member of 'std'**

Comment: @MohiburRahman you should start reading documentation rather than expect babysitting all the time. Click on link for `std::next` documentation and there is information there which header needs to be included. If you use old compiler that does not support C++11 you can use `std::advance` or simple loop, but better switch to better compiler. There are many which are free to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot-- @Slava

Answer (score 4):

[`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) has [Bidirectional Iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator). They are not random access iterators, so you cannot directly skip ahead arbitrary number of elements. If you want the Nth element from a given iterator (from `begin` in this case) you must advance the iterator that many times. Fortunately, there is the [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) function which will do it for you.

Try

```
it = s.begin();
std::advance(it, k);
```

Answer (score 3):

You want `std::next`:

```
it = std::next(s.begin(), k);
```

But note that as index increases, it gets more and more slow. If possible, you should try different approach.

---

Perhaps you're trying to iterate over a set?

Then you should use

```
for (long long it : s)
    std::cout << it;
```

or

```
for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); it++)
    std::cout << *it;
```